# error: constructor Miclass in class Miclass cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors, private, public

I'm trying to compile this in java and get this error: error: constructor Miclass in class Miclass cannot be applied to given types.
what's happening?

```
class Miclass {
    public int x;
    private int y;
    protected int z;

    public Miclass(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}

public class A extends Miclass {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
            Miclass m_class = new Miclass(2, 4, 8);
            System.out.println("m_class.x = " + m_class.x);
            System.out.println("m_class.y = " + m_class.y);
            System.out.println("m_class.z = " + m_class.z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is already a constructor defined in `Miclass` you need to add a constructor in `A` that invokes this constructor in the super-class:

```
public class A extends Miclass {
    public A(int x, int y, int z) {
        super(x, y, z);
    }

    // methods/fields specific to `A`
    ...
}
```

The code will not compile after this change as the variable `y` is not visible to `A`. To allow the code to compile you can add a getter method to access the variable.

Answer (score 2):

I have correct your code, try this, and read my explanation after..

```
  class Miclass {
        public int x;
        private int y;
        protected int z;

        public Miclass(int x, int y, int z) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }

        public int getY()
        {
            return y;
        }

    }

    public class A {
        public static void main(String [] args) {
                Miclass m_class = new Miclass(2, 4, 8);
                System.out.println("m_class.x = " + m_class.x);
                System.out.println("m_class.y = " + m_class.getY());
                System.out.println("m_class.z = " + m_class.z);
        }
    }
```

Comment: and you should remove `extends Miclass` since `Miclass` have been invoked in `Miclass m_class = new Miclass(2, 4, 8);`

Answer (score 0):

- Java provides default no-arg constructor only when there is no other constructor defined
- In this case you have defined a constructor with 3 int arguments for class Miclass and you have not called it from class A which extends Miclass
- due to this, when a default no-argument constructor will be provided to A class, a call to super no-argument will be done which is not possible because you do not have a no-argument constructor in Miclass
- to solve these issues you will either have to create a no-arg constructor in superclass or create a constructor with 3 int arguments.
- also your variable is not visible in class A because private variables are visible only in the same class